# Speed-up experiment, limit Spark to single core

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a Speed-up experiment with a Spark job. Unfortunately, I can't seem to limit Spark to truly one core. (I have 128)

I use the following settings to try and achieve this:

```
os.environ['NUMBEXPR_MAX_THREADS'] = partitions
os.environ['NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS'] = partitions
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "1") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "1") \
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "50g") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

[image: speed-up]

I do get a nice speed-up curve, but I can also see on htop, that the job is still using much more than one core.

[image: htop]

I'm running the spark job in a screen, and htop in a second terminal. That htop uses CPU is ok. but I don't understand why the topmost process still uses more than 100% of CPU. (100% is equivalent to one core fully used). Instead, this process sometimes goes up to 400%, in single-core setup. It doesn't seem right. also, there are several other processes popping up when I start the spark job, and they use a lot of CPU as well.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can force Spark to truly use one core?
and preferably not fan out over all of the cores (not ~1% usage on each, but 100% on one)

PS: Most important to limiting Spark so far seem to be the partitions. If they are set to default 200, Spark runs with full parallelization, even though it is told to use one core and one node...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [taskset](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html) command to limit a process to a single or multiple specified cores.

```
taskset -c 0 mycommand
```

```
-c, --cpu-list
    Interpret mask as numerical list of processors instead of a
    bitmask. Numbers are separated by commas and may include
    ranges. For example: 0,5,8-11.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it!  
I still have other tasks taking up some CPU (one also up to 100%) but I'll accept those to be outside my control :) Maybe the second big one is simply the master node... All in All: my major Process doesn't take more than 101%, that's close enough for me!

Answer (score 1):

When you create your spark session, you can set the number of cores when setting master, just pass `local[1]` instead of `local`, as follow:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]")
```

See [master's method scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$$Builder.html#master(master:String):org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder):

> Sets the Spark master URL to connect to, such as "local" to run locally, "local[4]" to run locally with 4 cores, or "spark://master:7077" to run on a Spark standalone cluster.

Comment: still at up to 400% at times, but thanks for the suggestion!